# Dini or Right or upper derivative of Weierstrass function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Is it true that the right-side derivative of Weierstrass function, which is a classic example of continuous yet nowhere differentiable function, always non-negative? (In fact, positive)

That is, given $f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a^ncos(b^n\pi x)$ for $0<a<1$, and $b$ a positive odd with $ab>1+3\pi/2$, is it true that for every $x$,

$\lim\sup_{h\to0+} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}\geq 0$?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think so. Let $x=2k/(b-1)$ with integer $k$; then $b\pi x = \pi x+2\pi k$, and therefore $b^n\pi x \equiv \pi x \bmod 2\pi$ for all $n$. The numbers $b,k$ can be such that $\sin(\pi x)>0$. Then every term of the series has negative derivative at $x$. Of course one cannot differentiate this series term by term,  so, an elaborate proof is likely needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your conjecture fails in two rather strong ways.

Corollary 11.4.1 on p. 128 of **[1]** states a result that is slightly stronger than the following, where $D^{+}f$ is the right upper Dini derivate of $f.$

> Let $I$ be an open interval in $\mathbb R$ and let $f:I \rightarrow {\mathbb R}$ be a function. If $f$ is continuous and $D^{+}f \geq 0$ on $I$ (or even just $D^{+}f(x) \geq 0$ for all but countably many $x \in I),$ then $f$ is non-decreasing on $I.$ Hence, by [Lebesgue's theorem on the differentiability of monotone functions](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/lebesgue-s-theorem-for-the-differentiability-of-monotone-fun), it follows that $f$ has a finite 2-sided derivative almost everywhere in $I.$

Thus, your assertion about the Weierstrass function fails --- your assertion implies differentiability almost everywhere and the Weierstrass function is differentiable nowhere.

Theorem 4.3.8 on p. 44 of **[1]** states the following (reworded slightly here), where $D^{+}f$ is the right upper Dini derivate of $f$:

> Let $I$ be a nonempty open interval in $\mathbb R$ and let $f:I \rightarrow {\mathbb R}$ be continuous on $I$ and nowhere differentiable on $I$ (means: for each $x \in I,$ the 2-sided derivative of $f$ at $x$ does not exist finitely). Then $D^{+}f$ takes on every real value in every nonempty open subinterval of $I.$ In fact, more is true --- for each real number $r,$ the set $\{x \in I: \; D^{+}f(x) = r\}$ has cardinality $c.$ Note this easily implies the following stronger version --- for each real number $r$ and for each nonempty open subinterval $I_0$ of $I,$ the set $\{x \in I_{0}: \; D^{+}f(x) = r\}$ has cardinality $c$ (follows by applying the previous result to $f$ restricted to $I_{0}).$

Thus, your assertion about the Weierstrass function $W$ fails --- your assertion is that $D^{+}W(x) < 0$ for no $x,$ but we actually have $D^{+}W(x) < 0$ for continuum many $x.$ In fact, in every nonempty open interval we have $D^{+}W(x) = -2744$ for continuum many $x,$ and in every nonempty open interval we have $D^{+}W(x) = -10^{100}\sqrt{17}$ for continuum many $x,$ and in every nonempty open interval we have $\ldots$

**[1]** Andrew Michael Bruckner, [**Differentiation of Real Functions**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0821869906), 2nd edition, CRM Monograph Series #5, American Mathematical Society, 1994, xii + 195 pages. [Review of 1980 1st edition](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bams/1183545222) (Note: Both of the results above are also in the 1980 1st edition, same chapter-section-item number, but the page numbers are different.)

Comment: Could you share a brief sketch of the idea behind the proof of Corollary 11.4.1 in your reference? Perhaps on this thread: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/282889/a-function-with-a-non-negative-upper-derivative-must-be-increasing/695894#comment5482094_695894

Comment: @David: OK, I just posted an answer in the thread you indicated. I didn't have much time (less than an hour), so I wasn't able to proof-read it as much as I usually do for advanced technical answers like this.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I can prove following the ideas of the original proof of Weierstrass. For a real number $r$ denote by $\langle r\rangle$ the unique integer such that
$$
-\frac12<r-\langle r\rangle\le\frac12.
$$

Let $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

1. If there is a sequence of integers $m_k$ converging to $\infty$ such that $\langle b^{m_k}\,x\rangle$ is odd for all $k$, then
   $$
   \limsup_{h\to0+} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=+\infty.
   $$
2. If there is a sequence of integers $m_k$ converging to $\infty$ such that $\langle b^{m_k}\,x\rangle$ is even for all $k$, then
   $$
   \limsup_{h\to0-} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=+\infty.
   $$
   In this case case I have not been able to prove anything about the sign of the right upper Dini derivative.

Comment: I don't think your argument is correct !  As far as I remember the Weierstrass function  had many (infinitely many) local maximum points.  And it is evident that at local maximum point upper Dini derivatives is $\leq$