# Nonnegative Dini derivative implies nondecreasing function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

This was posed as one of the proposition in my lecture note:

> If $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and one of its Dini derivative is everywhere nonnegative on $(a,b)$, then $f$ is nondecreasing on $[a,b]$

I can't prove it; it seems like you need some sort of variant of Mean Value Theorem in order to prove it. However, some of the result here might suggest that this result is false (see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/695894/156462).

So the question is this: is the proposition true, and if so, how's the proof going to be?

Answer (score 1):

Not a complete answer, here is the proof whenever $D^+ f > 0$ is assumed.

We will proceed by contradiction, suppose that there exist $m,n \in [a,b]$ such that $m>n$ but $f(m) < f(n)$. Therefore the interval $[f(m),f(n)]$ is not empty, and there exists $\mu$ such that $f(m) < \mu < f(n)$. Since $f$ is continuous, by Intermediate Value Theorem, there exists $r$, such that $f(r)=\mu$.

Assuming this setting, one of the natural way to produce a contradiction is to prove that $D^+ f(r) \leq 0$.

To do this, we need to have some informations about our $r$, amongst any proofs of Intermediate Value Theorem, there is a proof [given [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem#cite_note-2) in wikipedia] that provides the information of $f$.
We just need to modified it a little, let
$$S_{\mu}:=  \{ t \in [n,m] \, :\,  f(t)>\mu \}$$

Obviously, the set $S_{\mu}$ is non-empty and bounded, and hence it has a supremum, say $r=\sup S_{\mu}$. We will prove that $f(r)=\mu$, suppose that $f(r) > \mu$, by continuity $\lim_{x\rightarrow r} f(x)>\mu$, therefore there exists a neighbourhood of $r$ (i.e $-\delta < x-r < \delta$) such that $f(x)>\mu$, but $r+\frac{\delta}{2}$ is in this neighbourhood, thus $f\left(r+\frac{\delta}{2}\right)>\mu$, contradicting $r$ is supremum. If $f(r)<\mu$, then $f(x)<\mu$ for $-\delta < x-r <\delta$, but since $r$ is supremum, for any $\delta>0$, there exists $x_{\delta}$ such that $x_\delta - \delta < r$ and $f(x_\delta)>\mu$, clearly $x_{\delta}$ is inside the neighborhood, contradiction. Thus $f(r)=\mu$.

By the definition of $r$, we have for $x>r$ then $f(x)\leq f(r)$. Also for any $\epsilon>0$ there exists $x_{\epsilon} \in \{ t \in [n,m] \, :\,  f(t)>\mu \}$ such that $r-\epsilon < x_{\epsilon}$.

By definition

$$D^+f(r)= \inf_{\delta>0}\sup_{0<h<\delta}\frac{f(r+h)-\mu}{h} $$

Since $h>0$, we have $h+r > r$, thus $f(h+r) \leq \mu$, this means $D^+f(r) \leq 0$, contradiction.